# I don't know what's going on am I being scammed?

Tags: sugar-daddy

I had a gentleman reach out to me through my Instagram, he said he was going to start sending me money saying he was looking for a sugar baby. I said okay and we started talking, he had asked me to set up a cash app so I can receive the money, the more we were talking he ended up telling me that I need to send him $150 for a verification fee, now mind you this is my first time getting a sugar daddy and I'm not sure if that is normal for him to do. I've asked him several times what the verification fee is for and he would go around my question and never answer, he's also telling me that his lawyer is the one who will be sending me the weekly payments.. I just want to know if being asked for a verification fee is normal

Comment: Browsing the [sugar-daddy](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sugar-daddy) tag here should tell you all you need to know.

Answer (score 5):

Speaking as an IT Security professional who sees literally *hundreds* of these types of scams come over email and other digital mediums regularly in literally *thousands* of different forms, I can say this safely (as it has nothing to do with the 'sugar baby' / 'sugar daddy' set of things in general, and more 'common sense' knowledge about the Internet at large):

**This is almost 100% a scam, and in many cases most of the 'sugar daddy' type scenarios run into here online are scams or untrustworthy.**  ***NEVER*** trust someone randomly reaching out to you randomly offering you money but asking you to provide an up-front 'verification fee', they're going to take your $150 and then run.  This is a common tactic of scammers and such who are preying on people who 'want money' (sugar babies, etc.) to just steal your money.  This is a common tactic on *many* different types of scams, such as the historic Nigerian Prince scams, the ongoing "Hey, I have millions of dollars for you but need bank details" scams, and a nearly limitless number of similar scam trends actively going on in the real world today.

The common attack tactics for this are email driven scams but social media outreach via messages and such are becoming larger and larger mediums for this type of behavior and scams, so you should be **ultra concerned** when you receive such messages out of the blue.  **You should immediately report this user to Instagram for fraudulent/scammy behavior and attempting to scam you, and you should remove the cash app and not send a single penny to this person.**

Comment: (Note this really has no impact on money / personal finance, and more your security - this is definitely scamming going on with this 'person')